# js Плавная анимация блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вообщем есть блок с паралаксом полный код приводить не буду он чутка большой.
Высота данного блока статична так же в этом блоке есть кнопка которая разворачивает и сворачивает контент. Нужно чтобы при разворачивании и сворачивании данного блока менялась высота блока с параллаксом, но там стоит jquery 1.12.4 и у меня нифига не работает, вот как у меня это счас код:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1900) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".toggle").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.paralax').animate({
                    height: '630px !important',
                }, 550);

                $('.main').animate({
                    height: '675px',
                }, 550);

                $(".slideTogg").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Функция имеет такой вид по двум причинам; высота параллакса на каждом экране разная и я хз как определять развернут или свернут блок.

Так работать я её заставил завернув в забавную функцию:

```
JQuery(function($) {
    // вот сюда запихну весь код что выше
});
```

Однако блок с параллаксом не увеличивается, хотя должен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какие ограничения по поддержке браузерами. Может быть стоило посмотреть в сторону CSS анимации?

Если я всё правильно понял, то нужно что-то похожее на мой пример.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/skorolchuk/pen/pKWLGL)

```js
const createClickHandler = function(elClass, toggleClass) {
  let selected = false;

  return function onclick(event) {
    selected = !selected;
    console.log(event);
    if (selected) {
      document.getElementsByClassName(elClass)[0].classList.add(toggleClass);
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName(elClass)[0].classList.remove(toggleClass);
    }
  };
}

document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0].addEventListener('click', createClickHandler('slider', 'selected'));
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #201fa250;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 95vh;
  min-width: 95vw;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.round-border {
  border: 10px solid #1e0fa24f;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  min-height: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: #2e0fa2a0;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.slider.selected {
  max-height: 450px;
  min-height: 450px;
  min-width: 450px;
  max-width: 450px;
  /* approximate max height */
}

.clickable {
  color: white;
  font-size: 28em;
  margin-top: -0.2em;
  display: flex;
}

.clickable::before {
  content: '֍';
}
```

```html
<div class="container center">
  <div class="slider center round-border">
    <div class="clickable"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```